# How to solve the problem of eight hetmans in new way?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a program that solves the famous chess problem of the eight queen's. A description of the problem can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle

The problem has many solutions, so in order to give the user the option to choose, the program will load the location of one of the hetmans at the beginning. Then he will arrange the remaining 7 figures so that they do not attack each other.

There may not be a solution for some inputs, so the program must be prepared for it. The program must also deal with incorrect entry.

Entrance
The program reads from the standard input the position of one of the hetmans in algebraic notation.

Exit
The program outputs to the standard output the list of positions of eight hetmans or the message about the lack of solution.

Example
Enter the position of one of the queens: a2
a2 b4 c6 d8 e3 f1 g7 h5

I stack here:
(diagonal doesn't work well, doesn't complete taken place by "0" and I don't know how to exchange numbers into letters to continue to work somehow)

```
n = 8
board = [[0] * n for row in range(n)]


def playField(self, area):
  area = input('Give position of hetman: ').upper()
  x = area[0]
  y = area[1]
  print(area[0].isdigit())
  if x.isdigit() or y.isdigit():
    if int(x)>n or int(x)<1 or int(y)>n or int(y)<1:
      print("Wrong position, give new one: ")
      playField(board, area)
    else:
      print(area[0],area[1])
      for row in range(n):
        for column in range(n):
          board[row][column] = 1  #complete board "1"
          board[int(x)-1][int(y)-1] = 69 #taken place complete "69" for now, later it will be "0" 
          if board[row][int(y)-1]==69:  #check taken row
            print("tag",board[row],board[int(y)-1])
            board[row][int(y)-1]=0 #complete taken row "0"
            print("taken row")
          if board[int(x)-1][column]==69: #check taken column
            board[int(x)-1][column]=0  #complete taken column "0"
            print("taken column")
          else:
            print('free')

      print("row,column: ", row,column)
      print("x,y: ", x,y)

      for row in range(n):
        for column in range(n):
          przX = abs(row - int(x))
          przY = abs(column - int(y))
          if (przX == przY):  #check taken diagonal

            print("diagonal:", row+1, column+1)


      print(board)

      for row in range(n):
        for column in range(n):
          if(board[row][column]==1): #if in place is "1" it means it is result
            print("results: ",row,column)


  else:
    print("wrong")
    playField(board, area)




playField(board, n)
```

I try to implement this code, but still doesn't work:

```
n = 8
board = [[0] * n for row in range(n)]

def play_field(board, n, x, y):
    print(x, y)

    answers = solve(n,x,y)
    first_answer = next(answers)

    print(list(enumerate(first_answer, start=1)))

def get_position(n):
    """Prompt a user for a string resembling F2 and return coordinate pair.

    Fails for values above 9 / I."""  # docstring; explains what the function
                                      # does and its limitations. Optional.
    while True:
        position = input('Give position of hetman: ').upper()
        if len(position) != 2:
            print("Position must be 2 characters long.")
            continue  # restart the while True: loop
        x_str, y_str = position
        try:  # attempt to run the following code
            x = "ABCDEFGHI".index(x_str)  # outputs the location in the string
                                          # where the value of x_str can be found
                                          # (starts counting at 0)
        except ValueError:  # if x_str wasn't in "ABCDEFGHI"
            print("The first character must be a letter.")
            continue
        try:
            y = int(y_str) - 1  # Python starts counting at 0, so we need to
                                # make sure 1 becomes 0, 2 becomes 1 etc.
        except ValueError:  # if y_str couldn't be converted to an int
            print("The second character must be a number.")
            continue
        if not (0 <= x < n and 0 <= y < n):
            print("Values out of range.")
            continue
        return x, y  # return x and y, exiting the loop

def under_attack(col, queens):
        return col in queens or \
               any(abs(col - x) == len(queens)-i for i,x in enumerate(queens))

def solve(n,x,y):
        solutions = [[x,y]]
        for row in range(n):
            solutions = (solution+[i+1]
                           for solution in solutions 

                           for i in range(n)
                           if not under_attack(i+1, solution))
        return solutions



x, y = get_position(n)
play_field(board, n, x, y)
```

Comment: This is _almost_ a good question. What's the problem? Where are you stuck? We can't help you unless we know that.

Comment: The calculation of the occupied diagonal space does not work well, does not enter 0 in the table in the occupied space, and I do not know how to exchange numbers into letters to continue to work somehow.

Comment: Could you edit this into your question? Also, could you clarify "The calculation of the occupied diagonal space does not work well, does not enter 0 in the table in the occupied space"?

Comment: diagonal doesn't work well and doesn't complete taken place by "0"

Comment: I still don't know what you mean.

Comment: I don't know how to say it in different way. Could you check the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle ? Here is a detailed description of the issue of what my problems result from.

Comment: I think we understood well the eight queens puzzle, this is quite famous, we just do not get what is your problem...

Comment: What is the 'taken place by "0"'? I think by "diagonal doesn't work well" you mean that it doesn't check the queen's diagonals properly, but I can't work out what "0" is.

Comment: If queen is in the place - enter "0" into the board. Also, I want to in taken row, column and diagonals will be "0". I don't know how to do this in another way.

Comment: @Rafael I've solved the input problem for you, and re-organised your code a little bit so it's easier to see the _actual logic_. I'll have to ask you to explain some of the bits of code though; I don't understand what some of them are meant to do.

Comment: I see, thanks for that. What exactly fragment you talking about?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I add coments to my code. I hope it will be understanding for you now.

Comment: @Rafael Yeah, that's not going to work. Try implementing one of the algorithms from the Wikipedia article instead.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I try it like you say and paste the result on main post. I don't konw why it shows results only for a1 position all times.

Comment: @Rafael You need to start with `[[x,y]]` instead of `[[]]`, and in order to do that you need to pass `x` and `y` into `solve`, and in order to do that you need to make it `def solve(n, x, y):` instead.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I did like you said and I have "StopIteration" error and I stack again.

Comment: @Rafael ... That means that there was no solution. I'm confused.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Could you look at it again. Maybe I do sth wrong. I really need it to work properly.

Comment: @Rafael I _really_ see the problem now. Your code isn't designed to work that way. Erm... I think it can be tweaked slightly.

Comment: @Rafael Fixed! See my answer.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 you probably think that I'm stupid but I use your function and I have the same "StopIteration" error. But when I try to replace `solutions = []` to `solutions = [[]]` it shows results only for a1 position again.

Comment: @Rafael No, my code was completely untested. Do you see what I'm trying to do there? If you can get that to work, great! I'm afraid I don't have much time to help you, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should really be split up into a few smaller functions. Let's start by changing the indentation level to four spaces and rename `playField` to `play_field` to conform to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and remove some blank lines. I'll also fix `play_field`'s arguments; they should be `board` and `n`, not `self` and `area`. (By convention, `self` should only be used for methods of a class; you haven't got a class here. Ignore whatever example you got that from for now.)

```
n = 8
board = [[0] * n for row in range(n)]

def play_field(board, n):
    area = input('Give position of hetman: ').upper()
    x = area[0]
    y = area[1]
    print(area[0].isdigit())
    if x.isdigit() or y.isdigit():
        if int(x)>n or int(x)<1 or int(y)>n or int(y)<1:
            print("Wrong position, give new one: ")
            playField(board, area)
        else:
            print(area[0],area[1])
            for row in range(n):
                for column in range(n):
                    board[row][column] = 1
                    board[int(x)-1][int(y)-1] = 69
                    if board[row][int(y)-1]==69:
                        print("tag",board[row],board[int(y)-1])
                        board[row][int(y)-1]=0
                        print("taken row")
                    if board[int(x)-1][column]==69:
                        board[int(x)-1][column]=0
                        print("taken column")
                    else:
                        print('free')

            print("row,column: ", row,column)
            print("x,y: ", x,y)

            for row in range(n):
                for column in range(n):
                    przX = abs(row - int(x))
                    przY = abs(column - int(y))
                    if (przX == przY):
                        print("slant :", row+1, column+1)

            print(board)

            for row in range(n):
                for column in range(n):
                    if(board[row][column]==0):
                        print("results: ",row,column)


    else:
        print("wrong")
        playField(board, area)

play_field(board, n)
```

Now, the first thing to do is to move that "taking input" code into another function:

```
def get_position():
    area = input('Give position of hetman: ').upper()
    x, y = area  # pretty much the same as x = area[0]; y = area[1]
    print(x.isdigit())
```

I'm going to stop here because this is something that your program currently fails to do. Instead, I'm going to rewrite this function:

```
def get_position(n):
    """Prompt a user for a string resembling F2 and return coordinate pair.

    Fails for values above 9 / I."""  # docstring; explains what the function
                                      # does and its limitations. Optional.
    while True:
        position = input('Give position of hetman: ').upper()
        if len(position) != 2:
            print("Position must be 2 characters long.")
            continue  # restart the while True: loop
        x_str, y_str = position
        try:  # attempt to run the following code
            x = "ABCDEFGHI".index(x_str)  # outputs the location in the string
                                          # where the value of x_str can be found
                                          # (starts counting at 0)
        except ValueError:  # if x_str wasn't in "ABCDEFGHI"
            print("The first character must be a letter.")
            continue
        try:
            y = int(y_str) - 1  # Python starts counting at 0, so we need to
                                # make sure 1 becomes 0, 2 becomes 1 etc.
        except ValueError:  # if y_str couldn't be converted to an int
            print("The second character must be a number.")
            continue
        if not (0 <= x < n and 0 <= y < n):
            print("Values out of range.")
            continue
        return x, y  # return x and y, exiting the loop
```

Now we modify `play_field` to accept `x` and `y` as arguments, and to not check `area` or `x` or `y` themselves:

```
n = 8
board = [[0] * n for row in range(n)]

def play_field(board, n, x, y):
    print(x, y)
    for row in range(n):
        for column in range(n):
            board[row][column] = 1
            board[x][y] = 69
            if board[row][y]==69:
                print("tag",board[row],board[y])
                board[row][y]=0
                print("taken row")
            if board[x][column]==69:
                board[x][column]=0
                print("taken column")
            else:
                print('free')

    print("row,column: ", row,column)
    print("x,y: ", x+1,y+1)

    for row in range(n):
        for column in range(n):
            przX = abs(row - x)
            przY = abs(column - y)
            if (przX == przY):
                print("slant :", row+1, column+1)

    print(board)

    for row in range(n):
        for column in range(n):
            if(board[row][column]==0):
                print("results: ",row,column)

def get_position(n):
    """Prompt a user for a string resembling F2 and return coordinate pair.

    Fails for values above 9 / I."""  # docstring; explains what the function
                                      # does and its limitations. Optional.
    while True:
        position = input('Give position of hetman: ').upper()
        if len(position) != 2:
            print("Position must be 2 characters long.")
            continue  # restart the while True: loop
        x_str, y_str = position
        try:  # attempt to run the following code
            x = "ABCDEFGHI".index(x_str)  # outputs the location in the string
                                          # where the value of x_str can be found
                                          # (starts counting at 0)
        except ValueError:  # if x_str wasn't in "ABCDEFGHI"
            print("The first character must be a letter.")
            continue
        try:
            y = int(y_str) - 1  # Python starts counting at 0, so we need to
                                # make sure 1 becomes 0, 2 becomes 1 etc.
        except ValueError:  # if y_str couldn't be converted to an int
            print("The second character must be a number.")
            continue
        if not (0 <= x < n and 0 <= y < n):
            print("Values out of range.")
            continue
        return x, y  # return x and y, exiting the loop

x, y = get_position(n)
play_field(board, n, x, y)
```

**To be continued...**

---

**Continued...**

Replace your `solve` function with this to solve (pun a lucky accident) the problem:

```
def solve(n,x,y):
    solutions = []
    for row in range(n):
        solutions = (solution+[x if row==y else i+1]
                       for solution in solutions 

                       for i in range(n)
                       if not under_attack(i+1, solution))
    return solutions
```

The magic here is `[x if row==y else i+1]`, which forces the queen at row `y` to be equal to `x`.